# Looking to see if Blender is a good tool for an AI project

Tags: python, game-engine

I have an AI project that I'm working on. I have a machine learning algorithm for a robot, but I want to train it in simulation first. The experimental design is: The robot has a camera, and can see its own hand. It then makes random sequences of motor actions, and creates a causal link between what it saw in its camera, and the random set of motor actions.

I want a setup similar to this:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=T-c17RKh3uE1

What I want to know is, does the Blender game engine/python library give access to a camera and stream its input in real time, and is it possible to send motor sequences to a virtual arm? Or should I use a different tool? From the virtual camera, I don't require a raytracer, just having access to the pixel buffer is enough using, more over a high resolution isn't required, 1024x768 is plenty.

I can't test my models on a real arm/webcam due to funds. I am good with python, C and C++, I have written many export and mesh scripts for Blender, however I don't know how to set something like this up, or if it is possible. Any help/direction is greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: This is possible, but will probably require some very heavy coding in Python. Check out PyroEvil's [Neural Network](http://pyroevil.com/category/scripts-addons/neural-network/) Python scripts for Blender. You can see them in action [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mJaI2bnaq9Q) and [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jev4UA7EVkc) (more on the channel).

Comment: Not sure how up to date [this page](https://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Community:Science/Robotics) is. You may want to look at the work being done at [open robots](https://www.openrobots.org)

Comment: The R&D for my article [Torso Crowds](https://stuvel.eu/publications) was also done with the BGE. It took some changes in the C++ code too, but they were relatively simple additions & fixes, so they were easily accepted and thus are now part of Blender 

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In my mind, blender is a good fit for this sort of project. It has access to python allowing high level development and the use of many many libraries.

> What I want to know is, does the Blender game engine/python library give access to a camera

Yes - you can extract the pixels from a camera using the ImageRender refresh() method by passing in a buffer and pixel format. I have used this for a variety of purposes in the past, though not for robotics.
https://docs.blender.org/api/blender_python_api_2_78a_release/bge.texture.html#bge.texture.ImageRender.refresh

> and stream its input in real time,

You'd have to set something up

> and is it possible to send motor sequences to a virtual arm?

Yes. I wrote a minimal test scaffold for a UR5 robot arm. This allowed me to test a program intended for the actual hardware without needing the actual arm present. This was a huge help when trying to do a university project with limited lab time. I also somewhat sidestepped the project (with permission) by writing a blender script to generate the proper commands from the virtual setup....

> just having access to the pixel buffer is enough using, more over a high resolution isn't required, 1024x768 is plenty.

That should be possible - although you may find the GPU->CPU bottleneck on some hardware.

---

Some other things I have done with AI and blender include:

- Testing IK solutions.
- GUI's to display telemetry and provide control of various chassis,
- Prototype control algorithms for hardware (eg four wheel omni-steer chassis - how do you co-ordinate the wheels?)
- Robot hardware design - doing in in blender+BGE allows it to be tested inside the game engine before building it.